# Spring-OSGi with Mule ESB

Tags: esb

I am trying to use Sping OSGI with Mule ESB , any suggestion ? I tries to integrate Mule with OSGI but no luck , any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Is your interest on Mule or on an ESB which runs on an OSGi runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Mule isn't OSGI based, Kansun is right.  Another option for osgi is apache servicemix or apache karaf